# How to redraw only an invalidated part of OpenGL context? (for 2D GUI rendering)

Tags: opengl, user-interface, invalidation

I'm using OpenGL to optimize GUI rendering. When rendering the whole scene it works fine, but that's not optimal, since often only a small part is changed. So I tried this:

```
    glReadBuffer (GL_FRONT);
    glDrawBuffer (GL_BACK);
    glCopyPixels (0, 0, sz.X, sz.Y, GL_COLOR);
    glFlush();
```

This should copy front buffer to back buffer, so that afterwards I can change just a portion limited using glViewport. Unfortunately when a scene is changed, it looks like the glCopyPixels command is performed after the actual rendering, so that the original content sort of alphablends with the new graphics.

What is wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?
(for the record, when I do nothing, the front buffer starts blinking with back buffer and stuff like that...)

Comment: What about stenciling the gui element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but that's not optimal

What makes you think that? OpenGL and modern GPUs are designed on the grounds, that in the worst case you have to redraw the whole thing anyway and things should perform well in that situation, too.

> Or is there a better way to do this?

Yes: Redraw the whole scene. (Or what I suggest below)

To a modern low-end GPU which easily capable of throwing tens of millions of triangles to the screen per second, the few hundred to a thousand triangles of a 2D GUI are neglectible.

In fact your copying-stuff-around will probably a worse performance hit, than redrawing everything, because copying from the front to the back buffer is not a very performant operation and causes serious synchronization issues.

If you want to cache things you might split your GUI into separate widgets of content, which you draw to individually using FBOs into textures – design it in a way that widgets may overlap. You redraw a widget if its contents change. For drawing the whole window you just redraw the full window contents from the textures into the main framebuffer.

Comment: That's what I originally thought, but it's not true. The problem is NOT the GPU, it's CPU! A GUI may contain quite a few primitives and it takes time to prepare everything. To me the main goal is to relieve CPU. And unfortunately I found that when redrawing everything and say 30% of the GUI is repeatedly invalidated, software emulation becomes faster than GPU !!! Obvious reason - when rendering just a small portion, most of the widgets stay the same.

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: If you're CPU bound you're doing something wrong. I'd put my money on the use of immediate mode drawing (glBegin…glEnd) and some preparation overhead, that could be easily cached.

Comment: What you mean by "immediate mode drawing"? It's more or less the preparation overhead indeed, but it cannot be cached. As I said, we are talking about a very complex everchanging GUI, not a simple 3D scene.

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: If it's a constantly changing GUI then this is even more reason to go the full redraw route. It would really help to see some code of yours.

Comment: Well, all I can say is that the GUI is way too complicated for any kind of caching. Moreover isn't copying FB to BB exactly the same thing? Easy caching. Anyway now when I made it work it takes 5x less CPU than redrawing everything, so I consider it a success ;).

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: Well, at least draw to an FBO which you copy to the FB instead of copying from FB to BB. Why? Because the contents of the FB may get corrupted anytime. FBOs assure you, that they don't loose their contents.

Comment: I'm a little worried about that too, though so far it looks fine on both Windows & Mac OS X. With FBOs it seems OpenGL 3 is required, but unfortunately I need to support the most ancient GPUs and OSs... So I need to stick with OpenGL 1, pretty ugly...

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: FBOs are actually supported by even really old GPUs. They're available as an extension to OpenGL-1.1: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_object.txt you'll hard pressed to find a system with a OpenGL-capable GPU and drivers that doesn't support FBOs.

Comment: Btw wouldn't it be easier to use backbuffer instead? I mean to draw to BB and the instead of swapping copy it to FB. Or BB can be destroyed too?

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: The backbuffer is subject to the same effects as they happen on the front buffer. So no, using the back buffer is not a viable option. And unfortunately PBuffers (which are also widely supported) technically are not either, because the semantics of PBuffers allows their contents to get damaged as well. So the only safe bet are FBOs.

Comment: Ok thanks. I checked the docs for the extension and it looks like FBOs are about rendering to textures, am I right? If so, then we may have a problem - with the GL1 specs the textures must not only be 2^n in size, they also may be limited to 1024x1024, but my context may be bigger...

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: FBOs also can render into something called "render buffers", but textures are easier to use. OpenGL-1 imposes no limit on the maximum size of textures, but requires a minimum supported texture size. Yes, there is that 2^n limitation, but that's not really a problem, because you can tile your rendering into multiple textures. Also it would make sense to render each individual complex GUI element into its own texture.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no texture size limit? That doesn't seem to make sense to me also I read many posts about which GPUs support texture size above 1024 etc.

Comment: One more tring @datenwolf (since you seem to be the expert here) - I'm  using the immediate mode indeed. But do you think it would be advantageous to do it the other way, since the primitives I'm using are very simple - basically rectangular textures, none can really be cached, so it will always be 4 2D vertices, that's it. I don't see a difference when using vertex buffers except it gets more complicated and one needs to allocate these buffers. Also I'm not interested in immediate response, the global CPU use is the main factor, waiting is not a problem.

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: Yes there is a texture size limit, but the limit depends on the implementation at hand (read GPU), not on the OpenGL version. You can query it using `glGetIntegerv(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, …)`. –– The problem with immediate mode is, that each vertex drawn forces the CPU to go though the overhead of a function call and possibly a context switch. You don't have to use VBOs. Client Side Vertex Arrays would be just fine as well. So instead of calling glVertex 4*n times for each rect to be drawn, you'd call glDrawArrays exactly 1 time to draw all the n rects.

Comment: Thank you for the help datenwolf, it seems to work like charm now. Btw. for the record I did a little benchmark comparing immediate mode drawing for separate quads, thus always 4 vertices, and using vertex arrays, and the immediate mode is approximately 5% faster here. So it seems vertex arrays are worth it only with lots of vertices.

Comment: One more thing - it seems that most GPUs now support NPOTs. Do you think there could be a problem with rendering to NPOTs? It seems working on all machines I tried so far, but still...

Comment: @VojtěchMeldaMeluzín: Support for NPO2 textures has been around for a very long time. It's a core feature of OpenGL and was formally specified as an extension to OpenGL-1.4 since 2003, but actual GPU support dates back much longer (first NVidia GPU to support it appeared in 2000).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it seems this solves the problem:

```
    glDisable( GL_BLEND );
```

I don't know why, but it looks like before it was blending the data, despite I didn't find anything about it in docs and "glCopyPixels" doesn't seem it should do that.